# Rank features based on their frequency

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I have a sparse matrix of 0s and 1s that is training data = numpy 2d array.

I want to keep only the top K features to describe my data.

I want to calculate top K features based on their frequency i.e. how often they appear in training samples across the matrix.

However, I don't have exact names for the features. They are just columns.

How do I calculate their frequency, and, most essential, how do I then select the top K features in my matrix and remove the other features?

Comment: Every feature must be present in every sample of the data. That's how you supply it to scikit. What do you mean about frequency of features.

Answer (score 0):

Scipy sparse matrices can - up to their annoying tendency to return `matrix` not `array` objects - in many respects be used like `arrays`, so to extract the feature frequencies and find the top, say, 4:

```
>>> features_present_in_sample = [[1,5], [0,3,7], [1,2], [0,4,6], [2,6]]
>>> features_per_sample=[len(s) for s in features_present_in_sample]
>>> features_flat = np.r_[tuple(features_present_in_sample)]
>>> boundaries = np.r_[0, np.add.accumulate(features_per_sample)]
>>> nsaamples = len(features_present_in_sample)
>>> nfeatures = np.max(features_flat) + 1
>>> data = sparse.csr_matrix((np.ones_like(features_flat), features_flat, boundaries), (nsaamples, nfeatures))
>>>
>>> data
<5x8 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
        with 12 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
>>> data.todense()
matrix([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]])
>>> frequencies = data.mean(axis=0)
>>> frequencies
matrix([[ 0.4,  0.4,  0.4,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.4,  0.2]])
>>> top4 = np.argpartition(-frequencies.A.ravel(), 4)[:4]
>>> top4
array([6, 0, 2, 1])
```

remove others:

```
>>> one_hot_top4 = np.zeros((nfeatures, 4), dtype=int)
>>> one_hot_top4[top4, np.arange(4)] = 1
>>> data @ one_hot_top4
array([[0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

or (better):

```
>>> one_hot_top4_sparse = sparse.csc_matrix((np.ones((4,), dtype=int), top4, np.arange(4+1)), (nfeatures, 4))
>>> data @ one_hot_top4_sparse
<5x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
        with 8 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
>>> (data @ one_hot_top4_sparse).todense()
matrix([[0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 1, 0]], dtype=int64)
```